# Can we differentiate Einstein mass-energy relation $E=mc^2$ with respect to position $x$ to get force?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, mass-energy

The question is as the title.
Can we differentiate Einstein mass-energy relation $E=mc^2$ with respect to position $x$ to get force?

I don't know whether my question is valid and logical but just curious about knowing it.

Comment: No, you cannot do Special Relativity that way.  You need to learn it properly.

Comment: There isn't any position involved in that relation anyway; $c$ is a constant, so you would just end up getting $\frac{dE}{dx}=\frac{dm}{dx}c^2$.

Comment: But actually it is E = ymc^2 and y=1/(1-v^2/c^2) so v is present their and if we differentiate we must have something in terms of force and velocity gradient so why we can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship of $E=mc^2$ is not used much any longer in particle physics.
The m in the Einstein relation  is the [relativistic  mass](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/tdil.html#c3) , useful for science fiction spaceship velocities .

One uses [four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) whose "length" is the invariant mass of the particle or system described by the four vector.

In addition the force is  $F=dp/dt$ .